# how to copy data from one table to another table in Access

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

i need to  data from one table to another table in Access,i Have table1 with 10rows i need to copy only ProductId,ProductCat to Table2 with ProductId,ProductCat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do SQL

this is off the top of my head, so hopefully it works!

INSERT INTO Table2 (ProductId, ProductCat) SELECT Table1.ID, Table1.Field1 FROM Table1;

Comment: this is not working i need script that will run all over the Table1 and copy all to Table2 ,and this asking me what to insert

Comment: this is inserting data from Table1 into Table2, is this not what you want?

Comment: Yea i have Table1 full with info i created new table2 with only 2 row, i just need  script  that will copy all info from this two rows in table 1 to new table2 i cant just do it 1 by 1

Comment: I had updated it prior to your comment, from what I originally put.  Can you try this again please?

Answer (score 0):

Luckily the names for the columns are optional so you can also let Access copy every column without naming them explicitly:

```sql
insert into [TargetTable] select [SourceTable].* from [SourceTable];
```

[INSERT INTO statement (Microsoft Access SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/insert-into-statement-microsoft-access-sql)